# C# namedpipes server/client

Tags: named-pipes

I am trying to learn how named pipes work so i can connect two c# applications.

I wrote two basic C# applications for testing but it doesn't work.

When i start the connection the first application freezes waiting for input and after i sent input from application 2 it defreezes and button1 shows. But nothing appears in the textbox, any ideas why?

Application1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Hide();

        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe");
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        StreamReader s = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
        textBox1.Text = s.ReadToEnd();

        pipeServer.Close();

        button1.Show();
    }
```

Application 2:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("testpipe");
        if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) pipeClient.Connect();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);
        sw.WriteLine("%s", textBox1.Text);

        pipeClient.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the `NamedPipeClientStream` before the `StreamWriter` has flushed any data to it. Therefore when you read data from the server stream, there's no data to read before the connection is closed, so you get an empty string.

You can fix this by properly disposing of the StreamWriter, as so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream("testpipe"))
    {
        if (pipeClient.IsConnected != true) pipeClient.Connect();
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("%s", textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set `AutoFlush` to `true` on the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: i replaced my code with yours in the second application but now the first applications becomes unresponsive after i send the text. anything i should change there?

Comment: I had the name of the pipe wrong in the code above (`"test pipe"` versus `"testpipe"`). Try with the correct name now.